# Plots not shown in R Studio on MacBook Air

Tags: r, plot

This is a new R user who has some problem producing plots in the plot pane in R Studio on MacBook Air.
Plots were able to be produced one or two weeks ago, but were not produced after restarting R Studio this week.

[image]

tlmgr and related packages have been installed as the two terminal screenshots shown below before any trials to produce the plots.

[image]

The code producing the plot is as follows:

```
periods <- list("Nov 2000", "Feb 2001", "May 2001", "Aug 2001", "Dec 2001")
fcasters <- list( "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8", "f9")
fcastpanel <- data.frame(matrix(replicate(9,sample(1:10,45,rep=TRUE)), ncol = length(fcasters), nrow = length(periods)))
                                
rownames(fcastpanel) <- periods
colnames(fcastpanel) <- fcasters


tikz(file = paste(variable, '_forecasts_per_period.tex', sep = ''),
     height = 2.5, width = 5, pointsize = 11)
p5 <- ggplot()
p5 <- p5 + geom_line(data = NULL, aes(x = periods,
                                      y = rowSums(fcastpanel),
                                      linetype = 'Pre-filtering'))

p5 <- p5 + expand_limits(y = 0)
p5 <- p5 + ylim(0, 65)
p5 <- p5 + ylab('No. of Forecasts')
p5 <- p5 + xlab('Year')
p5 <- p5 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 8))
p5 <- p5 + scale_linetype_manual(values = c(2, 1))
p5 <- p5 + theme_bw()
p5 <- p5 + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank(),
                 legend.direction = 'horizontal', legend.position = c(0.5,0.1))
dev.off()
print(p5)
```

Not sure why the plot can't be reproduced even after the packages are updated.

Much appreciated if some solutions could be available.

Comment: As a suggestion to simplify your question: Does it generate plots for `plot(1:10)` or `ggplot() + theme_dark()`?

Comment: Just updated all the packages, and it works now. Thanks for your time.